# ¿Como puedo hacer que al crear un nuevo POST este se muestre de primero en la pagina de inicio?

Tags: mysql, sql

actualmente me encuentro creando un blog básico con php, y mysql pero a la hora que creo un nuevo post este se muestra de ultimo lugar osea después de los anteriores que he creado, pero me gustaría que este apareciese de primer lugar por ser el mas reciente y así sucesivamente.

Aqui les muestro una imagen de como se encuentra actualmente, lo que me gustaria es que las nuevas publicaciones se muestren de primer lugar, en este caso 'Prueba #3' fue la publicación mas reciente pero se muestra de ultimo lugar. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: imagen]

CODIGO: index.php

```
<div class="cuadro">
        <h1 class="mensaje">Acciones Recientes</h1>
                <h3 class="subtitulos">POSTS AGREGADOS</h3>
                <div class="capitulos-rc">
              <?php foreach ($posts as $key => $post): ?>
             <tr class="capitulos-tr">
              <td><?php echo $key +1; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $post['title']; ?></td>
            </tr><br>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
```

CODIGO: posts.php

```
if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id']; 
    }
}
```

CODIGO: db.php

```
function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
    
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }
```

TABLA BASE DE DATOS:
[image: IMAGEN 2]

Comment: Listo, edite la publicación y los agregue @BetaM

Comment: Si no me equivoco creo que ya la agregue @BetaM

Answer (score 4):

Toma una columna que sirva para realizar el ordenamiento de forma [descendente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html), es decir desde el último registro hecho (el mas reciente) hasta el mas antiguo (el primero que fue hecho).

Considero que la forma mas efectiva de hacer el ordenamiento sería basándonos en una columna de tipo [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) (*si es que esta existiera*), para tener un registro de fecha y tiempo de cada renglón y así obtener de manera mas acertada el resultado esperado.

Pero como no existe, entonces toma el id que figura según veo como `AUTO INCREMENT` y `PRIMARY KEY` y escribe una consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Agregue el datetime y como puedo establecerlo, ya que usando SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY id DESC me genera un error.

Comment: Que error te genera?

Comment: Se mantiene igual no hace ningún cambio, y al crear un nuevo post ahora dice: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE title=? LIMIT 1' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php:17

Comment: El error no se genera por mi consulta, edita tu pregunta y agrega tu Select tal cual lo tienes para identificar el error

Comment: Listo, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: y que debo cambiar para acomodar eso??, aun soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo mucho que debo hacer.

Comment: Yo considero que ese error debes publicarlo en una nueva pregunta ya que está tenía la intención de saber cómo ordenar y es lo que te di, entonces sería mejor una pregunta nueva con el error expuesto